# Should stack repl load test modules from *other* packages?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have a project which pulls in two local packages. My `stack.yaml` has:

```
packages:
- '.'
- '../creatur-wains'
- '../creatur-wains-test-utils'
```

Both `creatur-wains` and `creatur-wains-test-utils` define a module called `ALife.Creatur.Wain.TestUtils`, but in `creatur-wains` it's only part of the test code, not part of the library. This wasn't a problem when I was using ghci. I could load both packages, and only the version of `TestUtils` from `creatur-wains-test-utils` was visible.

However, Stack also seems to pull in the test modules from `creatur-wains`, so I get the following error:

```
$ stack repl
The following GHC options are incompatible with GHCi and have not been passed to it: -Werror -threaded
Configuring GHCi with the following packages: creatur-dvector-wains, creatur-wains-test-utils, creatur-wains

* * * * * * * *
The following modules are present in multiple packages:
 * ALife.Creatur.Wain.TestUtils (in creatur-wains, creatur-wains-test-utils)
* * * * * * * *

Not attempting to start ghci due to these duplicate modules.
Use --no-load to try to start it anyway, without loading any modules (but these are still likely to cause errors)
```

I can work around this using `--no-load`, and adding the packages one by one, but that's a bit tedious. Is this desireable behaviour for `stack repl`, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `stack ghci` docs (https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/ghci/):

> Similarly to stack build, the default is to load up ghci with all libraries and executables in the project.

So, to load just one package you need to do `stack ghci creatur-wains`.